# Why doesn't "System Idle Proccess" make cpu hot and consume power?

Tags: cpu, process, cpu-usage, power-consumption

I recently found out that there is a proccess called "System Idle Proccess", which takes all of the CPU time while it's idle so that the computer doesn't crash or freeze.

Why doesn't the CPU get hot or consumes the same amount of power as when it has load on it?

Comment: Because the process does not create any real load in a machine that is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CPU cannot ever be actually doing literally *nothing*. It must always be doing something.
So, when it has nothing better to do it runs System Idle Process.

This is basically a way of twiddling its thumbs while it waits for something else to do.
The process takes up almost no resources at all, it's just like tick-over on a car engine at a red light. It's not going anywhere, but it's ready for when you put your foot down to be instantly available to get you on the move again. [I suppose this is even true for the modern cars that switch off the engine at a red light - they're still watching for when you need to set off again].

Refs:
Wikipedia - [System Idle Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Idle_Process)
Ask Leo - [What is the System Idle Process and Why Is It Using Most of the CPU?](https://askleo.com/what_is_the_system_idle_process_and_why_is_it_using_most_of_the_cpu/)

Comment: Perhaps it might be worth mentioning System Idle Process execute in a special low-power mode (dedicated halt instruction or other technical solutions) which is why the CPU does not get hot. This is described in the Wikipedia article you have linked to.